# Uploading a File from Client to Server Displays Incorrect path: tmp\neotmp3547547292957915297.tmp

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to upload a file (whatever the type of file) to a server using ColdFusion. So i tried the following lines:

```
<cfform action="form.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="ScanCopyofthequotation" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</cfform>

<cfif isdefined("form.submit")>
    <cffile
        action="UPLOAD"
        filefield="Form.ScanCopyofthequotation"
        destination="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Devlopment\Mani\Backup\"
        nameconflict="MAKEUNIQUE">
</cfif>
```

It uploads fine. But while displaying the path which is selected by `<input type="file" ...>`  it displays the following path
*C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\neotmp3547547292957915297.tmp*

I tried to solve this. But failed. Could anyone please help to display the exact path?

---

I have a ColdFusion form:

```
<cfif not IsDefined("form.Submit")> 
    <cfform action = "cfmail.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 
       ScanCopy :   <cfinput type="file" name="scancopy">
    <cfform> 
<cfelse> 
   <cfoutput> Scancopy : #scancopy#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

I tried to print the file which I'm uploading, but when printing that file name I get the following file path:

```
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\neotmp3547547292957915297.tmp
```

I tried cfdump also.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the directory, name and extension of the uploaded file on your server.

```
<cfdump var="#cffile.serverDirectory##cffile.serverFile#" />
```

Add it after your CFFILE tag.

Comment: You can use cfdump if you want to but for a simple string <cfoutput> works as well.  Cfdump is best for complex structures: Query objects, structures, arrays, scopes, components, etc.  If you want to know what all is available after the file is uploaded do a dump of the cffile structure.  <cfdump var = "#cffile#">

Answer (score 1):

So your file uploaded at your `destination` path. The file name you can get from `cffile.ServerFile`. By concatenating both you will get the full path.

Comment: Hi friends  Thanks to all for this help and i got solution by #CFFILE.ServerFile# itself. as well as i came to know there is one more solution by cfdump. Appreciate all your help. Thanks